# Is it possible to make a spoofing attack in a access point with same SSID target network?

Tags: wifi, wireless, spoofing

With an Evil Twin attack is it possible for the access point to send malware to connected devices? If it is, how can this be prevented?

Comment: Of course, but the victim has to be vulnerable. I'm not sure how the Evil Twin attack is required or even a factor. If you are on the same network, then you could *potentially* infect another machine.

Comment: _" is it possible for the access point to send malware to connected devices?"_ Yes and also it's possible to perform local network attacks since attacker and target are on the same network.

Comment: @schroeder how can i infect the device? i didn't see other ways i can infect them with spoof or MITM what else?

Comment: @game0ver How can malware be delivered to the target device? is it by MITM or Spoof to url or what?

Comment: mitm and fake URLs are a *path*, they are not exploits themselves - the target needs to be *vulnerable* to *something* and if it is, then you craft the path you need to exploit that vulnerability. Wannacry is an example of a vulnerability that could be exploited with just access to the same network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all it takes is for an attacker to have a stronger signal. Due to how common it is for institutions to have multiple access points for a single wireless network, BSSID(an access point hardware identifier) is no longer used for network identification.

An attacker can use an off-the-shelf device like a [Wifi Pineapple by Hak5](https://www.wifipineapple.com). An attacker could also use a custom device that also acts as a [rogue access point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_access_point) to perform a tailored attack(i.e., create a webpage with javascript that forces download) to a device. There are more sophisticated attacks, it may be worth looking into security of the [802.11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11) protocol or using [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) to sniff some of your own traffic and test out common attacks.

You can reduce your exposure to wireless attacks by using only trusted networks. If on public wifi use a [VPN](https://thewirecutter.com/reviews/best-vpn-service/), or just skip it and use a cellular hotspot you control.

Comment: How the tailored attack works i search on it but i didn't find something useful is it like MITM? or what tools they used for this kind of attack?

Comment: @hemaezzat, a tailored attack is simply an attack customized for a particular target. Writing your own exploit after reading academic research on system vulnerabilities specific to your victim is an example